# SSRS 2008 R2 Custom Groupings

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS 2008 R2 report that I am building in Report Builder 3.0.

The requirement is for the report to export to PDF and the PDF will be navigated via bookmarks created with the DocumentMapLabel attribute.

This PDF will need to have multiple pages which will represent different grouping of the data.

Take the below as an example.

```
Region    SVP    VP
USA       SVP1   VP1
USA       SVP1   VP2
EMEA      SVP1   VP3
EMEA      SVP1   VP4
USA       SVP2   VP5
```

I need the Document Map to be the following, which I believe will have to require some custom groupings that I cannot wrap my head around yet.

```
+ALL Regions
+USA
+EMEA
+SVP1
  +ALL Regions
  +USA
  +EMEA
  +VP1
     +ALL Regions
     +USA
     +EMEA
  +VP2
     +ALL Regions
     +USA
     +EMEA      
  +VP3
     +ALL Regions
     +USA
     +EMEA
  +VP4
     +ALL Regions
     +USA
     +EMEA
+SVP2
  +ALL Regions
  +USA
  +EMEA
  +VP5
     +ALL Regions
     +USA
     +EMEA
```

If no data exists for a specific region/svp/vp the group should be skipped. So in the example above SVP2 -> VP5 -> USA should not exist, but I show it in the tree for completeness and in hopes that it helps illustrate what I am trying to do.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I got something working. Here is what I did. I used my current report as a sub-report in another report and passed parameters to it. This allows me to write a different query to pull all the appropriate custom groupings that I need. So really this effort has transformed from an SSRS effort to being able to write a query that provides the appropriate records I can group on and then use a list to do the grouping and the list contains the sub report.